# How to find ID of item to delete in database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Right now I have a database loaded and displayed in a `ListView`.
I thought I finally had the delete option working fine, but I realized that when I delete an item, it deletes ALL instances of THAT item.

Here's my database delete method:

```
public boolean deleteContact(String item) {
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ITEM + "='" + item + "'", null) > 0;
}
```

Here's how I'm running the delete method:

```
db.open();
db.deleteContact("Orange");
db.close();
```

So obviously it's deleting all records that say "Orange", that much I know.
What I don't know how to do is how to find the ID of **just that selected item**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ListAdapter` has an method `getItemId()` to get the `_id` of an item for a given position. Use this to delete your row.

```
public boolean deleteContact(long id) {
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, "_id=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }) > 0;
}
```

Run the code like this:

```
ListAdapter adapter = getListAdapter(); // if you are on a ListActivity or ListFragment
db.open();
db.deleteContact(adapter.getItemId(pos)); // where pos is the postion in list, eg. from onItemClick()
db.close();
```